# How to get an appengine entity size in Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Is is possible to get the size of an entity?  It seems like it should be a simple thing to do but I can't see how.

I am seeing this

```
com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$RequestTooLargeException: The request to API call datastore_v3.Put() was too large.
```

but am not real sure the entitity is above 1mb.  Wish I could detect that if it is and do something about it.  Is it best practice to handle this case in a catch clause.

Comment: How does the class look that you give to put()? Is there any byte[] or image in there? Please post some code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want estimate size, you could get the size of protoBuffer to which this entity will be transformed on `put()` call:

```
EntityProto ep=EntityTranslator.convertToPb(entity);

int size=ep.propertySize();
```

Answer (score 0):

I get an estimation with this:

```
EntityTranslator.convertToPb(entity).maxEncodingSize();
```